# Difference between $(VARIABLE) and % pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am slowly fighting my way through the gnu make documentation jungle (although it's excellent — just a lot).

I encountered *pattern rules*:

```
%.png: file1 file2
    run command here
```

There are also wildcards usable as targets:

```
FILES = $(wildcard *.png)
```

Now I could write:

```
$(FILES): file1 file2
    run command here
```

Is there any difference between the first and the second use case?

Comment: Very clever question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `%.png`: If any other rule, in turn, asks for some file, which does not itself have an explicit rule, but ends in `.png`, then this rule will be invoked.

So, `%.png: %.jpeg` (for example) says, “unless there is a more specific rule, here is how to convert from a JPEG to a PNG image.”

`$(FILES)` is enumerating a list of dependencies that you might want to create. It's not really the sort of thing for the target of a rule, but rather, for the dependencies of one.

For example, a phony target like `images.zip: $(FILES)` could be used to say that all of the `$(FILES)` must be up-to-date before making `images.zip`.

Using wildcard sources is, of course, rather “dangerous” as missing files won't be detected by `make`, so it's possible to have a “falsely positive” result of a build.

Comment: Is there any problem with using `$(FILES)` as a target if the rule generates all the targets?

Comment: It would work (at least in GNU Make), but only if one execution of the rule creates *all* of the named targets — whereas `%.png` creates *one* target at a go.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. It helps me a lot.